# How do you change colors of something when you move your cursor to it?

Tags: button, colors, onmouseover

If you want to change colors of a button you use that onMouseOver to change the colour.
But what about tags like tables?

Answer (score 0):

May be this works:

1. Define css class for your table, say `tableClass`
2. Now define `tableClass:hover` css which will work on mouse hover.

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/harryjoy/h8gcq/1/)

Comment: Good! Tables are usually a b*tch to stlye :)